# How do you seal fasteners, seams, and pipe holes in DensShield

Tags: bathroom, shower, tile

I'm reading through the DensShield installation instructions and all I see is "flexible silicon" to be used to seal the fasteners and seams.  This seems extremely prone to failure after 10 to 20 years.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I've also followed the instructions of DensShield and used silicon. But later I found out they didn't specify about paintable or non-paintable and I used later, which gave me issues for either grout or joint-compound.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to seal seams and fasteners in dense shield is using a liquid membrane, ( RedGard, Aquadefense, Hydro Ban). These can be applied with a paint roller or paint brush.

I will always reinforce seams with a fabric made to use with the water proofing, altho some don't require it.